# How to apply functions from one interface to another interface while using generics on a base class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, base-class

I have two interfaces from a third party that have the same function. Since this is a third party's interface, I do not have the ability to attach a parent interface.

```
public interface IInterface1 {
     int Open(string stringName);
}

public interface IInterface2 {
     int Open(string stringName);
}
```

I am wanting to pass them into a base class

```
public class MyClass : BassClass<IInterfaceWithOpenFunction>
```

So that I can execute the same exact function on both classes the same way.

```
public class BassClass<T> Where T : IInterfaceWithOpenFunction, new() 
{
    private T item;
    public BaseClass(string stringName) 
    {
        item = new T();
        item.open(stringName);
```

I'm not wanting to make item dynamic as I'm wanting to keep the intellisense, how do I achieve this?

Somehow IInterfaceWithOpenFunction needs to consume the function open of the other interfaces while allowing me to Pass in the desired Interface to implement.

Comment: Those methods are not "the same exact function" as far as the language is concerned, precisely because they are in different interfaces. C# does not have duck typing (barring dynamics, which you've already discarded). Some kind of type check/conversion/adapter is going to be inevitable. There are lots of ways to skin that cat, for example, by working with a `Func<string, int>` delegate and some extension methods.

Comment: When I've had to deal with this type of issue I usually end up writing wrapper classes with a common interface.

Comment: @juharr, I do not own the interfaces, so how would I attach a common interface to them? I'm wanting to hopefully not do this at runtime.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `C# does not have duck typing (barring dynamics)` and also `foreach`, [example here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2007/07/18/duck-notation/)

Comment: @Flater: being technically correct is indeed the best kind of correct. I'll amend my remark to "it doesn't have user controllable duck typing".

Comment: @Demodave You inject them into the wrapper classes.  Just check out Gilad's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do in order to achieve this is create your own "parent" interface and derived classes each suitable for those different third party classes. Essentially you have different wrappers for the different non-related interfaces:

```
public interface IInterfaces
{
    int Open(string stringName);
}

public class DerivedForInterface1 : IInterfaces
{
    private IInterface1 _instance;
    public DerivedForInterface1(IInterface1 instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public int Open(string stringName) => _instance.Open(stringName);
}

public class DerivedForInterface2 : IInterfaces
{
    private IInterface2 _instance;
    public DerivedForInterface2(IInterface2 instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public int Open(string stringName) => _instance.Open(stringName);
}
```

And then your base class:

```
public class BassClass<T> Where T : IInterface
```

In the implementation described above the specific instances of the third party interfaces are given as dependencies to your wrappers. By doing so no implementation on `IInterfaces` has a default constructor and thus you need to remove the `new()` generic constraint. There are other ways to implement it such as passing dependencies though properties instead of constructors. The different ways have their pros and cons and one can check the differences.

---

As for this part of your code:

```
item = new T();
item.open(stringName);
```

I think that maybe instead of initializing the type, as you are doing, you'd rather have your class hold a reference to the initialized types. Could be that the wrapper classes that I showed can replace the `BaseClass` you currently have.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - you are right and corrected - took the code from question without paying attention..

Comment: How would you deal with variables get? set? would it be public bool enabled {{get return _instance.enabled} set {_instance.enabled = value;}}

Comment: @Demodave - It depends what you are trying to do. And also how big of a problem it is. basically you are creating wrappers to wrap those third party interfaces. Solutions will be different if it is exposing a single function or 15..

Comment: I ended going with this solution as it is what best suited my needs thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on intellisense and a single manager to rule them all, then something like this can do:

```
public class Provider1Wrapper : IInterfaceWithOpenFunction
{
    private Provider1 _provider; // Instance\Inject via CTOR

    public int Open(string stringName)
    {
        return _provider.Open(stringName);
    }
}

public class Provider2Wrapper : IInterfaceWithOpenFunction
{
    private Provider2 _provider; // Instance\Inject via CTOR

    public int Open(string stringName)
    {
        return _provider.Open(stringName);
    }
}

public static class ProviderManager<T> where T : IInterfaceWithOpenFunction, new()
{
    public static int Open(string stringName)
    {
        T providerWrapper = new T();
        return providerWrapper.Open(stringName);
    }
}


void Main()
{
    var result = ProviderManager<Provider2Wrapper>.Open(stringName);
}
```